# Removal of CSS space on website

Tags: html, css

Please help me remove the white space between the Marquee text border and the slider Image on https://jbpp.000webhostapp.com/Index.html. I know this is a wrong place to post..but please help me and save my day

Comment: Please post your code. Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to check How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to marquee in style.css file.

Answer (score 2):

And then set line height as 0px in that marquee text line. Thats looks good.
Here is the code below,

marquee #marq p {line-height:0x;}